# SQL Query Help: Probably Involves Group By

Tags: sql, join, group-by

My software runs on a few databases so I need to be generic (noticibly, I think a "distinct on" solution might work, but that isn't standard).

Say I have two tables defined as:

```
Table A: id, time (pk: id)
Table B: id(fk), key, value (pk: id, key)
```

Where the id of Table B is a foreign key to Table A and the primary keys are as specified.

I need the latest (in time) value of the requested keys. So, say I have data like:

```
id | key | value
1  | A   | v1
1  | B   | v2
1  | C   | v3
2  | A   | v4
2  | C   | v5
3  | B   | v6
3  | D   | v7
```

Where time is increasing for the id, and I want values for keys A and C, I would expect a result like:

```
key | value
A   | v4
C   | v5
```

Or for keys D and A:

```
key | value
D   | v7
A   | v4
```

Ideally, I'd only get n rows back for n key requests.  Is something like this possible with a single query?

Comment: Why don't you store `value` as an integer instead of a string? This would make things simpler and faster.

Comment: You want max A.time, or max B.value? Is `value` a string? An integer?

Comment: @João - I interpret the question to ask for the B.value corresponding to the max A.time.

Comment: Mark: The value is actually float, the example was just for illustration. Joao: See what dbenham said, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that no ID values will have the same TIME value.

I believe the following is about as generic as you can get with the option of running on as many databases as possible. But the trade off for platform flexibility is less than optimal performance.

The sub-query with alias t identifies the latest time available for each key.

```
select a.id,
       a.time,
       b.key,
       b.value
  from tableB as b
  inner join tableA as a
    on a.id=b.id
  inner join (
      select b2.key,
             max(a2.time) time
        from tableB as b2
       inner join tableA as a2 on a2.id=b2.id
       group by b2.key
  ) as t on a.time = t.time and b.key = t.key
  where b.key in ('D','A')
```

The WHERE clause could be moved inside the sub-query and it might perform slightly better on a database that has a primitive optimizer. But putting the WHERE clause in the outer query makes it easier to maintain, and also leaves open the possibility of creating a view without the WHERE clause. The WHERE clause can then be added to a select from the view.

A query using ROW_NUMBER() would be more efficient, or even better yet a query using something like Oracle's KEEP LAST. But those features would make the query more restrictive to certain platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I won't be able to test until Monday.  I'll get back to you with results then.

Comment: Wow, that's impressive ... I'm fairly certain you got it. The only change I had to make was at the end where my db didn't like b2.key in (...) and I had to change it to b.key. I still have to confirm but I'm pretty sure you got it ... nice work! Thanks!

Comment: @rjcarr - Thanks. You are right, my WHERE clause was using the wrong alias. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is it working with SQL Server 2008 R2:

**Schema**

```
CREATE TABLE B (
   ind integer,
   [key] varchar(8),
   value varchar(16)
);

INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 'A', 'v1');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 'B', 'v2');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (1, 'C', 'v3');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 'A', 'v4');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (2, 'C', 'v5');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'B', 'v6');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'D', 'v7');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'A', 'v12');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'C', 'v17');
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 'C', 'v101');
```

**Query**

```
select [key], max(CAST(SUBSTRING(value, 2, LEN(value)) as INT)) from B
where [key] in ('A', 'C')
group by [key]
```

If you want to keep the v as a prefix, do this:

```
select [key], 'v' + CAST(max(CAST(SUBSTRING(value, 2, LEN(value)) as INT)) as VARCHAR) as Value
from B
where [key] in ('A', 'C')
group by [key]
```

**Output**

```
| KEY |    VALUE |
------------------
|   A |      v12 |
|   C |     v101 |
```

The SQL Fiddle to play with: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9de72/1

Comment: The query is simply getting some form of max(value), not at all how I interpret the question. My understanding is the OP wants to identify the most recent time {max(time)} available for each key, and then report on the value associated with that time. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12103059/1012053)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I won't be able to test until Monday.  I'll get back to you with results then.

Comment: dbenham was right, this isn't what I was asking for at all, sorry for the confustion, but thanks for the help.